# What does this error on account association failure mean?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-accounts

"We found differing IP addresses between sites for this association request - please return to Server Fault and try again."

I get this when trying to associate a newly created serverfault account with my stackoverflow account, but didn't get it when doing the same thing with meta and superuser accounts. This error message is almost useless to me (what IP addresses? Mine? Yours? Why is the IP Address relevant? I don't know the inner architecture of an account association request!).

Various combinations of logging in and out of stackoverflow/serverfault and retrying the association request all have failed. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Your IP is changing per-request, and more than just the last quad of the IP.

Comment: And why does that matter? And why doesn't the error message make that clear? And why did it only affect my attempts to link to serverfault and not meta/superuser? Why did it work from my home PC, then, which certainly has a completely different IP?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't entirely answer the question, as I still have no idea what caused the bug, but I was able to do the association from my home PC instead of my work PC.